# Expected value of unique elements of a multinomial distribution

Tags: probability

I have a multinomial variable, say $X$ $~$ Multi$(n, p)$, where $n$ is the number of possible outcomes and $\mathbf{p}$ is the vector of probability associated with each outcome.

Say I make k draws, each time one outcome is drawn (each outcome has an ID associated). I want to know what is the expected unique number of IDs.

Example:
$n= 10$ and $k = 5$ (i.e., $10$ unique IDs and $5$ draws)

One outcome might be $5,8,1,4,2$ in which case the unique number of IDs is $5$
Another outcome might be $2,2,3,5,2,$in which case the unique number is $3$.
So the expected value of that essential is what I am trying to find out.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example does not give $\mathbf p$.  Is it supposed to be uniform $(\frac1n,\frac1n,\ldots,\frac1n)$?  If so, there will be an answer involving Stirling numbers of the second kind.  If not then it will be difficult if $n$ is not small, and you might want to use simulation.

Comment: @Henry thanks for the note. It may or may not be uniform. Maybe you can share the answer using Stirling numbers of the second kind. In the more general case, I can refer to a simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this must have been asked and answered on the site before, but I could only find several instances of the question with equal probabilities but none with general probabilities.

This sort of problem is best solved using indicator variables and [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

The probability that outcome $i$ does not occur is $(1-p_i)^k$. Thus, by linearity of expectation, the expected number of outcomes that do occur is

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-(1-p_i)^k\right)=n-\sum_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)^k\;.
$$